# Compare 2 Panda series string columns and store the difference in new column/s

Tags: python, string, pandas, series, difflib

This is my first question.
I have a pd dataframe with two columns having string values.
I am presenting below a sample of the strings

```
s = pd.Series(['What * cool - you took 0% RTA * inr'])
r = pd.Series(['What : auto;bus;car;1;Metro cool - you took 0% RTA  = 0.38 inr'])
```

The above is a sample. both the series have 72 million rows each.

I need to do 2 things, for each row in the dataframe

A. Calculate the difference between two strings (of column s& column r) and 
B. store value for each * in a new column

**For A:** I am using below function (I copied from a stackoverflow post) for caluclating the difference and storing in a new column

```
def inline_diff(a, b):
    import difflib
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    def process_tag(tag, i1, i2, j1, j2):
        if tag == 'replace':
            return '{' + matcher.a[i1:i2] + ' -> ' + matcher.b[j1:j2] + '}'
        if tag == 'delete':
            return '{- ' + matcher.a[i1:i2] + '}'
        if tag == 'equal':
            return matcher.a[i1:i2]
        if tag == 'insert':
            return '{+ ' + matcher.b[j1:j2] + '}'
        assert false, "Unknown tag %r"%tag
    return ''.join(process_tag(*t) for t in matcher.get_opcodes())


for i in range(len(s)):
    df1['chang'][i]=inline_diff(s[i], r[i])
```

When I tried to timeit the above step for 20000 rows, i get a total time of approximately 30 minutes

```
start1 = time.time()
for i in range(len(s)):
    df1['chang'][i]=inline_diff(s[i], r[i])

end1= time.time()
print("Took %f ms in total" % ((end1 - start1) * 1000.0))
```

Took 1878017.782927 ms in total

**For B:** for creating new columns with changes values I am using below code (from a stackoverflow post)

```
df1[['f1','f2','f3']]=df1['chang'].str.extractall('(?<=\*\s->\s)([0-9a-zA-Z0-9\.;]+(?=))').unstack()
```

I need to perform the above for at least 10million rows. But the time taken as 30 minutes for 20K rows makes me sweat.

Can someone help me in creating code that can do the above steps more quickly

P.S. I am using a Mac pro with 8 GB ram and no GPU.

Comment: You could look into parallelizing the calculations using joblib : https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/